# Why is this error coming(ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=()). my python version - 3.7 and confusion matrix is also 2D

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, seaborn

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TZhq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWyY9.png)

Trying to print confusion matrix

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your confusion matrix is clearly not what you think it is.  Did you inspect it, either via the debugger or by printing it? Note that to be able to answer your question, reproducible code and data are needed.  Also the full error trace, in **text** format, often contains a lot of important information.